# Have facebook urls and want to show the names using these urls

Tags: php

I have facebook urls of users in the form of
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=
or http://www.facebook.com/vanityname

How do I get the name of the user?

Answer (score 0):

This information on the facebook graph api should get you started ...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/